# S3 Upload Trigger ( Multiple Files )

Tags: amazon-web-services

I have a `foo` lambda that executes some code by reading some files.

***I only want to run the lambda after I upload the 10 required files, which is the tricky part.***

1. 10 files are uploaded in S3 bucket via bitbucket pipeline
2. ??? (*need to wait for all new CSVs to be uploaded*)
3. Execute `foo` lambda

If I use S3 upload trigger it will not work because it will call the lambda 10 times for each file upload...

The 10 files already exist in the S3 repo, I just replace them.

Any ideas how to run only the `foo` lambda ONCE after the 10 files are uploaded?

Comment: Could you possibly upload a 'final' file that will always be the _last_ file, and use that to signal that the job should be run? You could do this by having the Lambda function check the filename. If it is not the 'last' file, then it can quickly exit.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein seems a good idea but the s3 file upload is async right? How can I make sure that file is the last one being uploaded?

Comment: You can't. You will need to code logic that figure it out. If you just want to count every 12th object, it won't be easy because Lambda functions can run in parallel. You could limit concurrency so that there is only one Lambda function running and it count keep a count 'somewhere'.

Answer (score 1):

The AWS Lambda function will be triggered for *every* object created in the Amazon S3 bucket.

There is no capability to ask for the Lambda function to run only after 10 files are uploaded.

You will need to add custom code to the Lambda function to determine whether it is 'ready' to trigger your work (and the definition of 'ready' is up to you!).

Comment: What would be the best way to trigger this new lambda once the files are uploaded in S3?

My pipeline currently uploads the file like `aws s3 sync carData s3://myBucket/cars/ --acl=private`

Now I need a way to trigger the lambda

Comment: [Tutorial: Using an Amazon S3 trigger to invoke a Lambda function - AWS Lambda](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-s3-example.html)

Answer (score 1):

This is a common situation in ETL World. request for a .OK file from source after completion of all data files to confirm that all required data files are transferred. trigger Lambda when .ok file is received.